# Footer is positioning itself at the top left of page and I cannot seem to make it go down

Tags: html, css

I am rebuilding a project from Codecademy without help from any videos or tutorials. I've gotten everything finished and looking great and only have my footer left to complete. Unfortunately, my structure is different than theirs and now that its all made I can't seem to get my footer to go to the bottom of the page. When I place the footer, it, by itself, positions in the top left.

I've tried to set the html, body to position: relative with a height. Tried making it a flex item. Tried the normal position: absolute, bottom 0. None of the above have worked. I'm convinced i've done something minor that is overriding everything else I just can't seem to find it :/...

```css
    /* Universal */
    a {
        color: #000;
    }
    
    li {
        list-style: none;
    }
    
    main {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
    }
    
    /* main div {
        border: 1px solid #000;
    } */
    /* Utility Classes */
    .column {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 1rem;
    }
    .img-content {
        font-family: Georgia;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 30px;
        color: white;
        padding: 1.2rem;
    }
    
    .head-content {
        font-family: Georgia;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 30px;
        color: black;
    }
    
    .main-story-img {
        font-size: 40px;
        }
    
    .narrative {
        font-family: Georgia;
        font-size: 17px;
        color: black;
    }
    /* Header & Navbar */
    header {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        font-family: Verdana;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        background: #fff;
        top: 0;
    }
    
    /* Logo */
    header .logo {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        color: mediumaquamarine;
    }
    
    header .logo h1 {
        font-size: 14px;
        margin-left: .75rem;
    }
    
    /* Nav Links */
    nav ul {
        display: flex;
        margin-right: 1rem;
    }
    
    nav ul li {
        margin: 1rem;
    }
    
    /* Main Content */
    /* Large Column */
    .column.large {
        width: 630px;
        margin-left: 2rem;
      }
    
    .main-img {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background: url('./images/main-story.jpg');
        height: 18.7rem;
    }
    
    .stories {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .story1 {
        padding-right: 1rem;
    }
    
    .story2 { 
        padding-left: 1rem;
    }
    
    .fall {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
        background: url('./images/fall-season.jpg');
        height: 18.7rem;
    }
    
    .hip {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
        background: url('./images/hipster-camerman.jpg');
        height: 18.7rem;
    }
      /* Medium Column */
      .column.medium {
        width: 300px;
      }
    
      .stories-medium {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
      .cat {
          display: flex;
          background: url('./images/cat-ceo.jpg');
          height: 18.7rem;
          align-items: center;
      }
      
      /* Small Column */
      .column.small {
        width: 240px;
      }
    
      .cookie img {
          margin-bottom: 0;
      }
      .cookie h3 {
          text-align: center;
          font-size: 1rem;
          margin-top: 0;
      }
    
      .bite {
          background: #f4f4f4;
      }
      .bites {
          border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
          padding: .5rem;
          color: #444
      }
    
      /* Footer */
      .footer {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/style.css">
    <title>My Times</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Header -->
    <header>
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="/resources/images/logo.jpg" alt="My Times">
            <h1>My Times</h1>
        </div>

    <!-- Navbar -->
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="world" class="links">World</a></li>
                <li><a href="u.s." class="links">U.S.</a></li>
                <li><a href="tech" class="links">Tech</a></li>
                <li><a href="science" class="links">Science</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <!-- Main Content -->
    <main>
        <!-- Large Column -->
        <section class="column large">
            <div>
                <div class="main-img">
                    <span class="img-content main-story-img">Mother of Three Buys Tuna Steak at Phish Concert. Leaves, "Feeling Funny."</span>
                </div>
                <div class="main-story">
                    <p class="narrative">MONUMENT VALLEY, AZ - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque nec nisl at augue dapibus dignissim. Nunc condimentum rutrum metus, ac eleifend lacus viverra nec. Proin ultrices egestas diam sed mollis. Nulla sapien massa, dictum vitae est et, pellentesque rutrum risus. Nunc volutpat, metus ac rutrum tempus, orci nisi porttitor dolor, sit amet luctus metus est ut mauris. Quisque vulputate nisl vitae massa rhoncus, at sagittis elit accumsan. Etiam tempus, lorem quis blandit imperdiet, enim dui lobortis tortor, sit amet lobortis arcu ex id odio. Nam fermentum nulla et eros bibendum, sed ullamcorper massa scelerisque. Vestibulum aliquet placerat leo a hendrerit. Nulla non sagittis neque. Nullam sit amet fringilla massa.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="stories">
                    <div class="story1">
                        <h2 class="head-content">Orca Spends Vacation at Land World Puget</h2>
                        <p class="narrative">PUGET, SO - Sed felis elit, faucibus et ipsum vel, vehicula ultrices purus. Sed congue odio vitae malesuada rhoncus. Integer vitae nisi pulvinar ante accumsan...</p>
                        <div class="fall">
                            <span class="img-content">Earth Spins Backwards for 2017</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="story2">
                        <h2 class="head-content">Burger for Breakfast: How Early is too Early?</h2>
                        <p class="narrative">Mew York, MY—Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque id quam facilisis, ultrices ante ut, rutrum enim. Praesent eu nisl erat.</p>
                        <div class="hip">
                            <span class="img-content">Research Shows Cameras Erase Memory</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Medium Column -->
        <section class="column medium">
            <div class="stories-medium">
                <div class="story">
                    <h2 class="head-content">FBI Finds Action Star Guilty of False Advertising</h2>
                    <p class="narrative">WASHINGTON DC- Donec luctus sem augue, rutrum posuere orci aliquam sed. Nam vitae aliquam lectus. Sed tempor tortor est, nec sagittis eros tincidunt sed. Morbi venenatis condimentum sem, vitae sollicitudin turpis pulvinar eget. Morbi pellentesque consectetur mi id auctor. Phasellus tincidunt orci mauris, placerat pharetra urna fringilla vitae. Morbi eget rutrum urna. Cras condimentum augue ut ante sollicitudin interdum. Pellentesque cursus dolor at tincidunt cursus. Vestibulum blandit aliquam felis...</p>
                </div>
                <div class="story">
                    <div class="cat">
                        <span class="img-content">Cats in Control-Is It a Thing?</span>
                    </div>
                    <p class="narrative">BROOKLYN, NY- In molestie nulla sodales sit amet. Proin vulputate, ipsum porta aliquam commodo, nunc nibh tincidunt lorem, vel consectetur neque mi vel neque. Mauris ultricies, nulla scelerisque sollicitudin lobortis, dui est sodales sapien, a vestibulum velit diam eget felis. Vivamus dignissim lacinia dolor, quis commodo tellus pellentesque in.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="column small">
            <div class="cookie">
                <img src="./resources/images/cookie.jpg" alt="News Bites">
                <h3>NEWS BITES</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="bite">
                <ul>
                    <li class="bites">Cat Emoji Goes Viral</li>
                    <li class="bites">Buy Youtube Views</li>
                    <li class="bites">Home Business Advertising Ideas</li>
                    <li class="bites">Advertising Internet Online</li>
                    <li class="bites">Illustration in Marketing Materials</li>
                    <li class="bites">Finally a Top Secret Way You Can</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <h3>MY Times</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="world" class=links>World</a></li>
            <li><a href="u.s." class=links>U.S.</a></li>
            <li><a href="tech" class=links>Tech</a></li>
            <li><a href="science" class=links>Science</a></li>
        </ul>    
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry I'm quite the noob at this. First post as I aim to learn... Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Change this on the `main` CSS.

```
position: relative;
```

Position absolute was taking that main section out of normal block flow, which makes your footer appear in the space that `main` used to be.

```css
/* Universal */
a {
    color: #000;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
}

/* main div {
    border: 1px solid #000;
} */
/* Utility Classes */
.column {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1rem;
}
.img-content {
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    padding: 1.2rem;
}

.head-content {
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: black;
}

.main-story-img {
    font-size: 40px;
    }

.narrative {
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: black;
}
/* Header & Navbar */
header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #fff;
    top: 0;
}

/* Logo */
header .logo {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: mediumaquamarine;
}

header .logo h1 {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: .75rem;
}

/* Nav Links */
nav ul {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 1rem;
}

nav ul li {
    margin: 1rem;
}

/* Main Content */
/* Large Column */
.column.large {
    width: 630px;
    margin-left: 2rem;
  }

.main-img {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: url('./images/main-story.jpg');
    height: 18.7rem;
}

.stories {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.story1 {
    padding-right: 1rem;
}

.story2 { 
    padding-left: 1rem;
}

.fall {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    background: url('./images/fall-season.jpg');
    height: 18.7rem;
}

.hip {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    background: url('./images/hipster-camerman.jpg');
    height: 18.7rem;
}
  /* Medium Column */
  .column.medium {
    width: 300px;
  }

  .stories-medium {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

  .cat {
      display: flex;
      background: url('./images/cat-ceo.jpg');
      height: 18.7rem;
      align-items: center;
  }

  /* Small Column */
  .column.small {
    width: 240px;
  }

  .cookie img {
      margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .cookie h3 {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 1rem;
      margin-top: 0;
  }

  .bite {
      background: #f4f4f4;
  }
  .bites {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
      padding: .5rem;
      color: #444
  }

  /* Footer */
  .footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/style.css">
    <title>My Times</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Header -->
    <header>
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="/resources/images/logo.jpg" alt="My Times">
            <h1>My Times</h1>
        </div>

    <!-- Navbar -->
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="world" class="links">World</a></li>
                <li><a href="u.s." class="links">U.S.</a></li>
                <li><a href="tech" class="links">Tech</a></li>
                <li><a href="science" class="links">Science</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <!-- Main Content -->
    <main>
        <!-- Large Column -->
        <section class="column large">
            <div>
                <div class="main-img">
                    <span class="img-content main-story-img">Mother of Three Buys Tuna Steak at Phish Concert. Leaves, "Feeling Funny."</span>
                </div>
                <div class="main-story">
                    <p class="narrative">MONUMENT VALLEY, AZ - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque nec nisl at augue dapibus dignissim. Nunc condimentum rutrum metus, ac eleifend lacus viverra nec. Proin ultrices egestas diam sed mollis. Nulla sapien massa, dictum vitae est et, pellentesque rutrum risus. Nunc volutpat, metus ac rutrum tempus, orci nisi porttitor dolor, sit amet luctus metus est ut mauris. Quisque vulputate nisl vitae massa rhoncus, at sagittis elit accumsan. Etiam tempus, lorem quis blandit imperdiet, enim dui lobortis tortor, sit amet lobortis arcu ex id odio. Nam fermentum nulla et eros bibendum, sed ullamcorper massa scelerisque. Vestibulum aliquet placerat leo a hendrerit. Nulla non sagittis neque. Nullam sit amet fringilla massa.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="stories">
                    <div class="story1">
                        <h2 class="head-content">Orca Spends Vacation at Land World Puget</h2>
                        <p class="narrative">PUGET, SO - Sed felis elit, faucibus et ipsum vel, vehicula ultrices purus. Sed congue odio vitae malesuada rhoncus. Integer vitae nisi pulvinar ante accumsan...</p>
                        <div class="fall">
                            <span class="img-content">Earth Spins Backwards for 2017</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="story2">
                        <h2 class="head-content">Burger for Breakfast: How Early is too Early?</h2>
                        <p class="narrative">Mew York, MY—Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque id quam facilisis, ultrices ante ut, rutrum enim. Praesent eu nisl erat.</p>
                        <div class="hip">
                            <span class="img-content">Research Shows Cameras Erase Memory</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Medium Column -->
        <section class="column medium">
            <div class="stories-medium">
                <div class="story">
                    <h2 class="head-content">FBI Finds Action Star Guilty of False Advertising</h2>
                    <p class="narrative">WASHINGTON DC- Donec luctus sem augue, rutrum posuere orci aliquam sed. Nam vitae aliquam lectus. Sed tempor tortor est, nec sagittis eros tincidunt sed. Morbi venenatis condimentum sem, vitae sollicitudin turpis pulvinar eget. Morbi pellentesque consectetur mi id auctor. Phasellus tincidunt orci mauris, placerat pharetra urna fringilla vitae. Morbi eget rutrum urna. Cras condimentum augue ut ante sollicitudin interdum. Pellentesque cursus dolor at tincidunt cursus. Vestibulum blandit aliquam felis...</p>
                </div>
                <div class="story">
                    <div class="cat">
                        <span class="img-content">Cats in Control-Is It a Thing?</span>
                    </div>
                    <p class="narrative">BROOKLYN, NY- In molestie nulla sodales sit amet. Proin vulputate, ipsum porta aliquam commodo, nunc nibh tincidunt lorem, vel consectetur neque mi vel neque. Mauris ultricies, nulla scelerisque sollicitudin lobortis, dui est sodales sapien, a vestibulum velit diam eget felis. Vivamus dignissim lacinia dolor, quis commodo tellus pellentesque in.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="column small">
            <div class="cookie">
                <img src="./resources/images/cookie.jpg" alt="News Bites">
                <h3>NEWS BITES</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="bite">
                <ul>
                    <li class="bites">Cat Emoji Goes Viral</li>
                    <li class="bites">Buy Youtube Views</li>
                    <li class="bites">Home Business Advertising Ideas</li>
                    <li class="bites">Advertising Internet Online</li>
                    <li class="bites">Illustration in Marketing Materials</li>
                    <li class="bites">Finally a Top Secret Way You Can</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <h3>MY Times</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="world" class=links>World</a></li>
            <li><a href="u.s." class=links>U.S.</a></li>
            <li><a href="tech" class=links>Tech</a></li>
            <li><a href="science" class=links>Science</a></li>
        </ul>    
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```